# How to change already set chrome options while running tests?

Tags: selenium, webrtc, chrome-options

While sharing screen from webrtc application, user gets 3 options. 
1. Share entire screen 
2. Share specific tab 
3. Share specific application

I need to automate these TC's. Have found a way to do it individually on different browser driver by setting chrome option like :

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--auto-select-desktop-capture-source=Entire screen")  -- for sharing entire screen.

But is there any way to perform all 3 cases using same driver by editing chrome option run time?

Comment: I looked and I can't find a dup but you can't change these options in an already running driver. You have to change the options and then launch a new driver. Having said that, even if you could... you don't want to do this. Best practice is that each test should be independent and should test one thing. Set up your framework to run in parallel and use several browsers and/or VMs and you get a huge speed boost to make up for the separate tests.